# JavaScript: Shorten each word in properties of object to fixed length?

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to take an object like:

```
 {
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_epoch": 1566522907515,
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
   "computer_general_initial_entry_date": "2018-08-18",
 }
```

And make each property name shorter so that each word better `_` characters of object keys are shortened to a fixed character length. So for instance, shortening to a fixed length of 3 characters would produce:

```
{
   "com_gen_las_con_tim_epo": 1566522907515,
   "com_gen_las_con_tim_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
   "com_gen_ini_ent_dat": "2018-08-18",
}
```

Would I have to create a new object? Iterate through each object in my current object, use regex to remove all '_' and then shorten each word then add them all together with _ inbetween? I'm super lost on this as I have objects with 100's of properties that I need to shorten for an integration and any advice would help!

Comment: *Would I have to create a new object?* <-- Yes, if you simply want to shorten the existing property names, but you can create a second set of property names on the existing object (by iterating over the keys) that simply map back to the longer named ones.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think creating a new object would be best due to having 100's of properties already in the object itself. That's good to know though for smaller objects in the future. Could you show me an example of that? Documentation, etc... I would be grateful to know that process if you could shoot me any resources. No worries if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to iterate each key of your input object, and perform the following per key to compute the new key to transfer values to:

1. Split key by "_" to get words from key
2. Trim each word to 3 letters
3. Join trimmed words with "_" to obtain new key

In code this can be expressed as:

```js
let obj =  {
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_epoch": 1566522907515,
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
   "computer_general_initial_entry_date": "2018-08-18",
 };
 
 const newObj = {};
 
/* Iterate keys in obj */
for(let key in obj){
  
  /* Create new key, split key by _ to extract words, trim each word to three
  letters, join trimmed words by _ again to obtain new key */
  const newKey = key.split("_").map(word => word.substr(0, 3)).join("_");

  /* Apply key value from obj to new obj with new key */
  newObj[newKey] = obj[key];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to shorten the existing property names, you'd create a new objecct, but you can create a second set of property names on the existing object (by iterating over the keys) that simply map back to the longer named ones.

```js
let obj =  {
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_epoch": 1566522907515,
   "computer_general_last_contact_time_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
   "computer_general_initial_entry_date": "2018-08-18",
 };
 
// Loop over the object
for(let p in obj){
  // Create a new string as you see fit
  let newProp = p.replace("computer_", "com_").replace("_general_", "_gen_").replace("_initial_", "_ini_").replace("_entry_","_ent_").replace("_date","_dat");
  // Add the new key that points to the existing value
  obj[newProp] = obj[p];
}

console.log(obj); // Updated object

// And then you can access the property with the new key
console.log(obj.com_gen_ini_ent_dat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should consist of two stages:

1. Create a property "shotification" function i.e.

```
function shortify(str) {
    return str.split('_').map(word => word.substr(0, 3)).join('_')
}
```

2. Iterate over initial object properties and generate a new one:

```
const newObject = {};
for (let key in originalObject) {
    newObject[shortify(key)] = originalObject[key];
}
```

The whole solution could look as follows:

```js
const initialObject = {
    "computer_general_last_contact_time_epoch": 1566522907515,
    "computer_general_last_contact_time_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
    "computer_general_initial_entry_date": "2018-08-18",
};

function shortify(str) {
    return str.split('_').map(word => word.substr(0, 3)).join('_')
}

const newObject = {};
for (let key in initialObject) {
    newObject[shortify(key)] = initialObject[key];
}
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "computer_general_last_contact_time_epoch": 1566522907515,
  "computer_general_last_contact_time_utc": "2019-08-23T01:15:07.515+0000",
  "computer_general_initial_entry_date": "2018-08-18",
}

// Note: this version works only for snake case .
function shortandObjectKeys(obj) {
  var newObj = {}
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var newKey = key.split('_').map(k => k.substr(0, 3)).join('_');
      newObj[newKey] = obj[key];
    }
  }

  return newObj;
}


console.log(shortandObjectKeys(obj));
```